# I recently rewrote my bot using switch case, now it doesnt respond to commands

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I have recently rewrote my bot using switch case
But now it doesnt respond to the commands
Instead, it just sits there and does nothing

Here is the code's link: https://sourceb.in/ff321fd803

Comment: Have you tried looking at what the command variable holds before the switch statement?

Comment: @tomerpacific I added a default case, now it runs that because no case else is true, but I console logged the command const it said function shift

Comment: Did it look like this? `[Function: shift]`

Comment: @Rover [I reproduced your code in a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lun0v62j/) and everything worked perfectly. Can you see any difference between the JSFiddle and your own code that might help?

Answer (score -1):

the problem is here

```js
const args = msg.content.slice('2').trim().split(' ');
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
```

- Slice would be better have as argument a number and not a string because it could cause an error if it's not possible to convert it into a number
- You cannot access "command" with the args variable since you removed the command from it.
- Args isn't well defined.

Use this :

```js
const args = msg.content.split(' ').slice(1)
const command = msg.content.split(' ').shift().toLowerCase()
```

Comment: Your method is fairly inefficient; Rover's would work fine if they fixed the error you pointed out.

Comment: Oh, I just tested it out and `slice()` will accept a string if it can be coerced to a number.

Comment: Oh okay, i changed the message ^^'

Comment: Also, Rover didn't remove the command from the args array until after the `command` variable was defined.